# Permutations Function

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner coder, and have been struggling with defining a function that would return all the permutations of a given array. My current code is:

```
def Permutations(array):
    result = []
    idx = 0
    for element in array:
        for number in range(len(array)):
            if number != idx:
                array[array.index(element)] = array[number]
                result.append(array)
                idx += 1
    return result
```

For some reason, I get a value error when I run the code. What is the issue with the code, as it seems to be logical to me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware you are modifying the input array while looping? `array[array.index(element)] = array[number]` Also, if you can give an example of input and expected output, it would simplify the debugging for whoever would like to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was not aware! I added a new variable NewArray which I set equal to array, so that way I can store the array in another variable without modifying the array in the loops. For some reason though, the code still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def Permutations(array): 
    result = [] 
    for id1, el1 in enumerate(array): 
        a = [el1] 
        for id2, el2 in enumerate(array): 
            if id1 != id2: 
                a.append(el2) 
        result.append(a) 
    return result
```

```
In [1]: Permutations([1, 2, 3])
Out[1]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]]
```

So what I changed here was:

- use `enumerate` instead of keeping a variable to track index
- keep separate list to construct a permutation then add it to the final set of permutations

Comment: Thank you! Although this works, it doesn't give all the permutations, as for [1,2,3], there are supposed to be 6 different ones...

Comment: Yes, my bad. There is a need for recursion. Will try that now